# Data is not showing up in Ajax Auto complete in ASp.net C#

Tags: c#, ajax

I have a text box and i have added AJAX AutocompleteExtender to this.. the code is given below..
From:

ANd is CS file file i have added

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
    public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Station"].ToString();

        string selectString = "SELECT *from Station";

        List<String> CustList = new List<string>(count);
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(selectString, sqlConn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                    CustList.Add(reader["DBRT"].ToString());//DBRT is the Column name

            }
        }
        return (CustList.ToArray());
    }
```

When i execute the code and type in that it is not showing anything while i type .What is wrong in  my code..

Comment: Have you verified that your list has anything . Does the autocomplete extender have to be inside of an Ajax panel?

Comment: Please put down your aspx page code, did you enable "usecontextkey" ?

Comment: Your code is correct. something going wrong in aspx page. There is no mistake in your code. post aspx source code

Answer (score 0):

With out using web service, this is how  i would have done. You can use web service as well if you want. Instead of returing string array  i am returning generic List.

In Aspx File

You can change the tag Perfix of Ajax controls according to yours, in my system Ajax control tag perfix start from asp.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"
EnablePageMethods = "true">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:TextBox ID="StationSearchTxtBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
    MinimumPrefixLength="2"
    CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10"
    TargetControlID="StationSearchTxtBox"
    ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" FirstRowSelected = "false">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

in CS file

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
    {

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
       string connString =    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings   ["Station"].ToString();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select StationName from Stations where " +
            "StationName like @SearchStation + '%'";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchStation", prefixText);
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            conn.Open();
            List<string> stations= new List<string>();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    customers.Add(sdr["StationName"].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            return stations;
        }
    }
```

Hope fully this code will give you way to solve your issue.

Comment: iT STILL DOESNT woRK this is my aspx code

 From:   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="86px"></asp:TextBox>        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox2_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox2" MinimumPrefixLength="1" 
          ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" UseContextKey="True"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
          
         When i do debuuging it contol is not going to CS file...

Comment: did you change the table name and table column and connection string according to yours?

Comment: yaa i have changed all necessary things  and i have tried to debug but the control just doesnt got to CS file

Comment: can you edit your code which you posted above to newer version after you made changes ...

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="86px"></asp:TextBox>  



       <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox2_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox2" <br>
        MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" UseContextKey="True"></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>

Comment: cs code as well please.. you can edit above code in your question.

Comment: public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Station"].ToString();

        string selectString = "SELECT *from Station;";

        List<string> CustList = new List<string>(count);
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();

            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(selectString, sqlConn))
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

Comment: can u please tell me ur ID i can mail it to u??

Comment: while (reader.Read())
                    CustList.Add(reader["DBRT"].ToString());
              
            }
        }
       
        return (CustList.ToArray());
    }

Comment: can you remove string contextkey from the method arguments and UseContextKey="True" from extender control, remove the count from List<string> CustList = new List<string>(count)  and try the query the way i send you ...see what you get